# Download zip file with login

Tags: 12.04

I need to download a zip file (backup of server with size 11GB) from interserver.net. It required login credentials.

How to add login credentials while

```
wget
```

command don't work with login detail.

Comment: Your question is quite unclear, I have no idea what exactly you are asking. Would a screenshot help clarify things?

Comment: Just do: `cd /some/specific/path; w3m ...`, since it downloads to the current directory by default. Or, when you select the file to download, it asks, at the bottom line: `Download to: <some-file-name>` - erase the filename and enter the full path + filename.

Comment: Have edit it to ask problem.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not seeing anything in the man pages about being able to download. You may need to use wget if possible.

```
 wget -O /desired/path/name.zip http://someplace.com/file.zip
```

If you need to log into the site, just modify the wget command as follows

```
wget --user username --password pass -O /desired/path/name.zip http://someplace.com/file.zip
```

or it may be

```
wget --user username --password pass http://someplace.com/file.zip -O /desired/path/name.zip
```

Edit: Since you said it did not work, lets drop the output option (if you havent already). Does

```
 wget --user user --password pass http://serveraddress/file.zip
```

do it for you? Obviously changing "user" with your username and "pass" with your password.

Comment: Actually, I have to login into website first. Thats why I am using w3m.

Comment: I've update the answer to include command to use to log in using wget

Comment: no success on this

Comment: updated one last time.

Comment: The page maybe having a login form, in which case HTTP authentication (via `--user`/`--password`) won't work.